# Map a Pandas series with a dictionary as argument, where the value is a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to map a column of my df with a dictionary. My dictionary contains tuple as value and I only want the first element of the tuple. How can I achieve that ?

```
my_dict = {'foo': (1, 0.1)}
df['original_column'] = 'foo'
```

what I get so far:

```
df['mapped column'] = (1, 0.1)
```

what I want:

```
df['mapped column'] = 1
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by new dictionary created by dictionary comprehension for get first value of tuple:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'original_column':['foo','bar','baz']
})

my_dict = {'foo': (1, 0.1), 'bar':(2,0.5),'baz':(5,6)}
d = {k:v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
df['mapped column'] = df['original_column'].map(d)
print (df)
  original_column  mapped column
0             foo              1
1             bar              2
2             baz              5
```

Another solution is map original and select first values of tuples by `str[0]`, but performance is worse if large DataFrame:

```
my_dict = {'foo': (1, 0.1), 'bar':(2,0.5),'baz':(5,6)}
df['mapped column'] = df['original_column'].map(my_dict).str[0]
print (df)
  original_column  mapped column
0             foo              1
1             bar              2
2             baz              5
```

Comment: I got that, but when you map the column, how do you access to the first element ?

df['mapped column] = df['original column'].map(my_dict) will return me the tuple, not the first element of the tuple